# MathJax, Rails 4, Markdown integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, markdown, ruby-on-rails-4, mathjax

Does anyone have an idea of how i can integrate:

Mathjax latest release(mathjax-MathJax-v2.2-8-g727332c), Rails 4 and Markdown?

This whole asset pipeline thing is making it hard for me to get to grips with how i can configure mathjax so that it can work with Markdown.

Any takers?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to implement MathJax via the CDN link download the latest version of Mathjax here: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/installation.html

(Via git: `git clone git://github.com/mathjax/MathJax.git MathJax`)

Create a new directory `app/assets/javascripts/mathjax` in your rails app and put the content from `MathJax/unpacked` into this new directory. (*You can remove unwanted **config**, **localization**, etc. files if you want*).

Also copy the entire `MathJax/images` directory and put it into your rails app under `app/assets/images`.

Now add the following code directly before the closing `</head>` tag like this:

```
<head>
  ...
  <%= javascript_include_tag "mathjax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full.js", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
</head>
```

To change your MathJax config just replace the content of the `config` parameter: `?config=my-config.js`

And voilà!

---

I don't know which system you're using for processing markdown but MathJax states (http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#tex-and-latex-in-html-documents) that the backtick (`) is used to mark verbatim text so it doesn't get processed by markdown before MathJax can lay its hand on it:

```
... we have `\(x_1 = 132\)` and `\(x_2 = 370\)` and so ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for the answer as well, and managed to finally figure it out.

Add the Mathjax CDN to youtapplication.html.erb file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

or add the rails gem (Although, it took me ~15 mins to install!)

https://github.com/manusajith/mathjax_rails

---

Then, just add your math stuff within a `<div>` and `$$` like so,

```
<div>$$(Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt\,.$$</div>
```

That should be it! Working for me and easier than I thought.
I'm sure there is a better way so we don't need that `<div>` in there, but I don't know it yet.

Hope it helps :D

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).